# Splitting a string from php post to something like this

Tags: php, dart

Still learning PHP functions at the moment, I would like to ask how one could split a string like this?

In dart, I have a function that splits every letter then append them to the last letter then adding them to an array.

Where finalProduct = "donuts"

```
List<String> splitList = finalProduct.split(' ');

 (int i = 0; i < splitList.length; i++) {

   for (int j = 0; j < splitList[i].length + i; j++) {

 indexList2.add(splitList[i].substring(0, j).toUpperCase());
    }}
```

The output is like this:

```
D
DO
DON
DONU
DONUT
DONUTS
```

I have this where the output right now is:

```
'$string = 'donuts';
        $arr1 = str_split($string);
        echo print_r($arr1);'
Array
(
    [0] => d
    [1] => o
    [2] => n
    [3] => u
    [4] => t
    [5] => s
)
```

How can I loop through each letter in PHP to so I can have the same result as the first example and save them to a new variable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following method:

```
$string = 'donuts';

$arr1 = array();
for($i=1; $i<=strlen($string); $i++){
    $arr1[] = strtoupper(substr($string, 0, $i));
}

print_r($arr1);
```

Please pay attention that for just outputting you even don't need the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```php
$string = 'donuts';
$sub_string = '';                       // initialize the variable to store the substring at each iteration
$sub_strings = [];                      // initialize the array containing all substrings
foreach (str_split($string) as $char) { // loop through each character in the string
    $sub_string .= strtoupper($char);   // capitalize the character and append it to substring
    $sub_strings[] = $sub_string;       // append current substring to array
}
print_r($sub_strings);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => D
    [1] => DO
    [2] => DON
    [3] => DONU
    [4] => DONUT
    [5] => DONUTS
)
```